# What is the rationale for margin-bottom on HTML elements like paragraphs, instead of margin on top and bottom?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margins

Is there a good reason why Twitter Bootstrap and other projects override the default browser margins on elements such as paragraphs?

Browser default (1em margin on top and bottom):

```
p { margin: 1em 0; }
```

Twitter Bootstrap (10px margin on bottom only):

```
p { margin: 0 0 10px; }
```

My preference (10px margin, or vertical rhythm length, on top and bottom):

```
p { margin: 10px 0; }
```

Here are my thoughts:

With margin on top and bottom, I can rely on margin collapsing to ensure that the margin is not too large between elements. I feel confident that elements that should be spaced from other elements will be.

With margin on bottom only, I must place paragraphs and similar in containers with padding, or risk having them flush against elements above them, or apply margin-bottom to anything that might be above them, to ensure that the design is spaced out.

Overall, I prefer the browser defaults. Is there something I'm missing? Are there blogs or articles that discuss this topic?

Answer (score 4):

This fiddle should demonstrate why: http://jsfiddle.net/men62/1/

It's about consistent layout of text in relation to its container and other elements.

Comment: But with a bottom margin, you still have the same problem at the bottom of the container.

Answer (score 2):

I am not too sure myself, but I suppose because in both writing rules and print design we are accustomed with this set of rule: each paragraph should have some margin on the bottom of it.

I recall in a writing class I've taken some time ago, bottom margin on each paragraph signifies a start on a new paragraph. In case bottom margin cannot be applied, an indentation could also be used as a mark of a new paragraph. [Wikipedia has some explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragraph) regarding this, based on Robert Bringhurst's book, *The Elements of Typographic Style*:

> *The Elements of Typographic Style* states that "at least one en
>   [space]" should be used to indent paragraphs after the first,
>   noting that that is the "practical minimum".
>
> ...
>
> Other techniques are possible. Lines can be outdented to signify the
>   start of new paragraphs. Another technique is to insert vertical
>   space between paragraphs. This creates what is sometimes known as
>   "block paragraphs".

On Word Processor softwares like Microsoft Word, it is also set by default that each paragraph has some spacing (usually 10pt) on the bottom of it. When it is get applied to the web, it seems the bottom margin technique prevails.

A [blog post from Marco Dugonjic](http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2007/05/12/quick-tip-bottom-margins-of-paragraphs-and-lists/) seems to suggest that "setting the bottom margin equal to element’s line height ensures correct vertical rhytm."